# ¿Por que no me funcionan las relaciones en Laravel 5.4.2?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hola amigos muy buenas mi problema es el siguiente, desde hace días llevo planeando como iban a ser las relaciones del juego que estoy haciendo con PHP usando Laravel 5.4 y me surge el siguiente inconveniente al crear usuarios: tengo dos Tablas: **users** y **characters**, un usuario puede tener muchos personajes pero un personaje solo un Usuario (uno a muchos) en la tabla **characters** tengo una columna llamada *user_id* la cual esta relacionada con la columna *id* de **users**, tengo entendido que si establezco las relaciones en las migraciones y en los modelos al yo querer registrar un usuario nuevo, la columna *user_id* en **characters** se llena automáticamente con el *id* del usuario acabado de registrar.

Me gustaría saber si estoy errado y si ese fuera el acaso mil disculpas y Gracias.

PD1: código de las migraciones y modelos los cuales menciono:

Modelo **User.php:**

```
   protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];
    public function characters()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Character');
    }
```

Modelo **Character.php:**

```
    protected $fillable = [
     'user_id',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

Migracion **characters:**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('characters', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

    $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
```

*PD2: Como solución temporal logre que el mismo formulario que registra también autentique la cuenta recién creada y usando el facade **Auth** pude acceder al id del usuario autenticado y llenar de esa manera la columna user_id en **characters** pero no se si eso sea lo adecuado.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que es una relación uno a muchos, la sintaxis correcta para la relación en el modelo User debe ser así:

```
public function characters()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Character');
}
```

En cuanto a como guardar la relación, el "método Laravel" sería algo así, creando primero el Usuario, luego el caracter y por último la relación, todo esto en el controlador, o donde tengas ubicada la lógica de esta sección:

```
$nuevoUsuario = User::create(['name' => 'ignacio zsabo', 'email' => 'correo@yo.com', 'password' => 'encriptada']);

$nuevoCaracter = Character::create(['name' => 'My weird character']);

$nuevoUsuario->characters()->save($nuevoCaracter);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, hice lo que me indicaste y no me funcionaba, adicional a eso agregue: **$newCharacter = Character::create([ 'name' => $request['c_name'], 'user_id' => $newUser->id ]);**, con eso funciono ya me crea el Character usando el ID del User, en el modelo **User** fue mi equivocación por que estaba probando de muchas maneras y la ultima fue **"hasOne"** Ya esta solucionado Muchas Gracias.